# What is a word for a thing that is overlooked/a thing of negligence?

Tags: single-word-requests

A "crack" in the system, but it's not damaged or harmful. I'm not looking for synonyms of negligence/overlooked, it's a word for the *thing*, conceptually, that is a result of negligence/being overlooked, like the word crack but not that exactly. All synonyms for crack don't work, either. Like, "an overlooking" or "an ignorance" but those words aren't used that way.

It's driving me nuts that this word is missing, or I'm missing it, so I'm reaching out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps you might try **oversight**

[MW.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oversight)

> 2 : an inadvertent omission or error (whether by oversight or intention— G. B. Shaw)

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/oversight)

> a mistake made because of a failure to notice something:

Examples:
MW.com

> The fact that you didn't get an invitation is surely just an oversight. The error was a simple oversight.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you so much, I knew there was a word for it. I just couldn't think of or search for it. I'm incredibly embarrassed now because I could've gotten there through "mistake" or something. The theoretical tip of my tongue appreciates your quick answer.

Comment: You can select this as the accepted answer.